# How to resolve span color style not listening when manipulated from JavaScript Command

Tags: javascript, html

Okay guys, I am building a user registration form with bootstrap and some JavaScript. I have a problem styling a span element id from JavaScript. I have a button that fires a JavaScript event handler that needs to validate the input a user enters into a form. I told my JavaScript function to check the length of the first field and if user enters nothing then this span needs to have a color of red and display the message `"Looks like we need this field"`, the message displays but the JavaScript styling does not work. Chrome's debug console displays the message `signup.html:99 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color') at validate (signup.html:99:55)`. Help me style my span element to be red from JavaScript(initially it is gray with the message `Enter your full names in the field above`).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Full Names</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="f_names" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Full Names">
    <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter your full names separated by a space</small>
  </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
<script>
 function validate(){
    //define the data field values
    let f_names=document.getElementById("f_names").value;
     if(f_names.length==0){
     //find the span error tag and fill its inner data
     //this line below throws an error
     document.getElementById("nameHelp").Style.color="red";
     document.getElementById("nameHelp").innerText="Looks like we need this field";
   }
}
</script>
```

Why isn't `element.style.color=` working and how can I workaround this?

Answer (score 1):

`style` property of the element must be lowercase

Comment: what about the color?

Comment: Changed the style to lower case, the error is gone but the color of the span element is still gray

Comment: I ran your code in JSFiddle w/ the change suggested by @jgondev, and it worked fine. Are there any errors in your console? The console would have alerted you to the original error too.

Comment: @user1599011, share the link to the JSFiddle please

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=dw2KsOVkJt

Comment: issue is solved?